# WAF WebACL Requests chart always empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

I want to create a simple rate limiting to my lambda.

WAF seems like a good solution to start with.
I decided to go with 100 requests for 5 min so I created a web acl rule in waf.
The rule matches all requests atm and blocks (I tried to check for ip at first using 'X-Forwarded-For' in the header).

I wanted to ensure the waf actually processes the requests so I sent a POST to my lambda  but the **Requests per 5 minute period** graph is always empty (it should contain allowed and blocked requests) and on the bottom details 'Sampled requests' are empty as well.

Not sure if I misunderstood how waf suppose to work, should I enable something or I am doing something wrong?

more details:
the time range is correct.
I have only 1 rule(priority 0) and I enabled logging and sampling (and created log group that starts with 'aws-waf-logs').
The api gateway logs show the right endpoint in cloud watch.
My user is admin so there is no permissions issue.

Thanks.